# How to split up content in a referenced entity in Twig?

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I am maintaining a project that was built by a sitebuilder and is frankly a bit of a mess.

I have some content types, that use custom blocks to add in the ability to enter location details e.g. address and geolocation (shown via leaflet).

Now, I need to be able to 'split' the output of this rendered entity so I can place the address in one part of the page, and the leaflet map in another.

I was obviously able to duplicate the output f the entire block by placing `{{ content.location_lock }}` in two parts of my node template.

But I was unable to see anyway to just output the address for example. I tried `{{ content.location_block.address }}` but that didn't work.

Is there a way to achieve this rather then spitting out the entire block and hiding the bits I don't want with CSS? (really don't want to go that route!)